# Display tiled image by leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tiles

I have some big images without geographic information which I want to load them by leafletjs.

I have two ideas:

1 Georeferring images first

Once the image contains geographic informaiton,  I can serve them by geoserver and generate tiles.

2 Use pixel coordinate

Is it possible to generate tiles directly and load them in leafletjs using the pixel coordinates? If yes, what's the projection in this case?

Comment: Do your images relate to anything geographically?

Comment: Yes, but the image itself contains no geographic information

Comment: For your solution 2, you would be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34638887/leaflet-custom-coordinates-on-image/34640343#34640343